# Total required in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a query in javascript.. Please check the below image
[image]

In Above image :

- First Input Box is Description
- 2nd Input Box is Qty
- 3rd is Value

I have got total qty using below script onchange of textbox :

```
function findTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    var $changeInputs = $('input.qtyValue');
    $changeInputs.each(function(idx, el) {
      total += Number($(el).val());
      });

  $('.total').text(total);
  $("#totalvval").val(total);
}
```

I have got total Value using below :

```
   function qfindTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    var $changeInputs = $('input.qqtyValue');
    $changeInputs.each(function(idx, el) {
        total += Number($(el).val());
        });

    $('.qtotal').text(total);
  $("#totalqval").val(total);
  if(total>10000){
      alert("Amount should not be greater than 10000");
  }
}
```

My query is that we need total of qty x value + qty x value  + qty x value =total

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your question, but this sort of thing is the reason why using frameworks exist (knockout, aurelia, angular etc) to separate your views from your data.  If the data was held in a logical JS object, you could probably loop through it very easily.  Not saying you can't do that with the elements on screen, but I'd recommend taking a look at what one of these frameworks would give you.

Comment: Please post your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0zfte9ns/1/)

#### Code

```js
function createHTML() {
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    html += "<input type='text' class='qty' id='txtQty_" + i + "' onblur='updateTotal()' />";
    html += "<input type='text' class='cost' id='txtQty_" + i + "' onblur='updateTotal()'/>";
    html += "<br/>"
  }

  html += "Qty Total: <span id='qty_total'>0</span>";
  html += "Cost Total: <span id='cost_total'>0</span>";
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html
}

function updateTotal() {
  var qty = document.getElementsByClassName("qty");
  var cost = document.getElementsByClassName("cost");

  var total_qty = 0;
  var total_cost = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < qty.length; i++) {
    if (qty[i].value && cost[i].value) {
      total_cost += qty[i].value * cost[i].value;
      total_qty += parseInt(qty[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("qty_total").innerHTML = total_qty;
  document.getElementById("cost_total").innerHTML = total_cost;

}

(function() {
  createHTML();
})()
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```